# Vault and TeamCity

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, teamcity-9.0, sourcegear-vault

I have TeamCity 9.1.6 up and running, and it was previously working with Vault 9.0.  I upgraded Vault to version 9.1, which is the latest, and now TeamCity errors when checking for source code changes.  The message is:

> Error collecting changes for VCS repository '"" {instance id=3, parent internal id=2, parent id=, description: "vault:
>   https:///VaultService"}'
>        Checkout rule: -:.
>        +://trunk => .
>         {internal id=3}: Exception occurred while trying to connect to Vault server. See original message below:
>        Argument for @NotNull parameter 'message' of jetbrains/buildServer/buildTriggers/vcs/vault/impl/VaultConnectionImpl.specifyMessage
>   must not be null

Stacktrace:

> jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsRootVcsException: Error collecting changes for VCS repository '"" {instance id=3, parent
>   internal id=2, parent id=, description: "vault:
>   https:///VaultService"}'
>
> Checkout rule: -:.
>
> +://trunk => .
>
> {internal id=3}: Exception occurred while trying to connect
>   to Vault server. See original message below:
>
> Argument for @NotNull parameter 'message' of
>   jetbrains/buildServer/buildTriggers/vcs/vault/impl/VaultConnectionImpl.specifyMessage
>   must not be null
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.ConnectionStateReporterImpl.reportConnectionFailed(ConnectionStateReporterImpl.java:14)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChangesByEachRule(LoadChanges.java:19)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChangesByCombinedRule(LoadChanges.java:42)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChanges(LoadChanges.java:47)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.VcsRootChangesLoader$RunLoadChanges.run(VcsRootChangesLoader.java:66)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.util.NamedThreadFactory.executeWithNewThreadName(NamedThreadFactory.java:89)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.VcsRootChangesLoader.loadChanges(VcsRootChangesLoader.java:94)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesFetcher$LoadChangesForRoot.run(VcsChangesFetcher.java:21)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesLoaderImpl$ImmediateFutureExecService$1.call(VcsChangesLoaderImpl.java:2)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.ImmediateFuture.get(ImmediateFuture.java:59)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.ImmediateFuture.get(ImmediateFuture.java:68)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.PeriodicChangesLoader.waitForTaskToComplete(PeriodicChangesLoader.java:20)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.PeriodicChangesLoader.loadChanges(PeriodicChangesLoader.java:26)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesLoaderImpl.tryLoadChanges(VcsChangesLoaderImpl.java:28)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.VcsModificationChecker$CollectChangesAction$1.run(VcsModificationChecker.java:14)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.util.NamedThreadFactory.executeWithNewThreadName(NamedThreadFactory.java:89)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.VcsModificationChecker$CollectChangesAction.run(VcsModificationChecker.java:6)
>
> at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>
> at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>
> at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Caused by: jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException:  {internal
>   id=3}: Exception occurred while trying to connect to Vault server. See
>   original message below:
>
> Argument for @NotNull parameter 'message' of
>   jetbrains/buildServer/buildTriggers/vcs/vault/impl/VaultConnectionImpl.specifyMessage
>   must not be null
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.ExceptionAwareConnection.toVcsException(ExceptionAwareConnection.java:43)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.ExceptionAwareConnection.login(ExceptionAwareConnection.java:117)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.EternalVaultConnection.ensureActiveConnection(EternalVaultConnection.java:44)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.EternalVaultConnection.refresh(EternalVaultConnection.java:67)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.SynchronizedVaultConnection.refresh(SynchronizedVaultConnection.java:77)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.VaultVcsSupport$3.collectChanges(VaultVcsSupport.java:261)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.utils.VcsPluginUtil.collectBuildChanges(VcsPluginUtil.java:99)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.vcs.api.services.collectChanges.CollectRepositoryChangesPolicyFactory$7.collectChanges(CollectRepositoryChangesPolicyFactory.java:3)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.vcs.api.services.collectChanges.SingleVersionCollectChangesCommand.collectChanges(SingleVersionCollectChangesCommand.java:0)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.vcs.api.services.collectChanges.CollectChangesServiceProvider$1.collectChanges(CollectChangesServiceProvider.java:4)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges$CollectChangesForCheckoutRules.call(LoadChanges.java:0)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges$CollectChangesForCheckoutRules.call(LoadChanges.java:1)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsOperationProgressProviderImpl.runWithProgress(VcsOperationProgressProviderImpl.java:27)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChangesWithProgress(LoadChanges.java:49)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChangesForCheckoutRules(LoadChanges.java:24)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChangesByEachRule(LoadChanges.java:34)
>
> ... 20 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull
>   parameter 'message' of
>   jetbrains/buildServer/buildTriggers/vcs/vault/impl/VaultConnectionImpl.specifyMessage
>   must not be null
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.impl.VaultConnectionImpl.specifyMessage(VaultConnectionImpl.java)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.impl.VaultConnectionImpl.login(VaultConnectionImpl.java:260)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.impl.VaultConnectionImpl.login(VaultConnectionImpl.java:238)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.DelegatingVaultConnection.login(DelegatingVaultConnection.java:49)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.ExceptionAwareConnection.login(ExceptionAwareConnection.java:115)
>
> ... 34 more
>
> jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException:  {internal id=3}:
>   Exception occurred while trying to connect to Vault server. See
>   original message below:
>
> Argument for @NotNull parameter 'message' of
>   jetbrains/buildServer/buildTriggers/vcs/vault/impl/VaultConnectionImpl.specifyMessage
>   must not be null
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.ExceptionAwareConnection.toVcsException(ExceptionAwareConnection.java:43)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.ExceptionAwareConnection.login(ExceptionAwareConnection.java:117)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.EternalVaultConnection.ensureActiveConnection(EternalVaultConnection.java:44)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.EternalVaultConnection.refresh(EternalVaultConnection.java:67)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.SynchronizedVaultConnection.refresh(SynchronizedVaultConnection.java:77)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.VaultVcsSupport$3.collectChanges(VaultVcsSupport.java:261)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.utils.VcsPluginUtil.collectBuildChanges(VcsPluginUtil.java:99)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.vcs.api.services.collectChanges.CollectRepositoryChangesPolicyFactory$7.collectChanges(CollectRepositoryChangesPolicyFactory.java:3)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.vcs.api.services.collectChanges.SingleVersionCollectChangesCommand.collectChanges(SingleVersionCollectChangesCommand.java:0)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.vcs.api.services.collectChanges.CollectChangesServiceProvider$1.collectChanges(CollectChangesServiceProvider.java:4)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges$CollectChangesForCheckoutRules.call(LoadChanges.java:0)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges$CollectChangesForCheckoutRules.call(LoadChanges.java:1)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsOperationProgressProviderImpl.runWithProgress(VcsOperationProgressProviderImpl.java:27)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChangesWithProgress(LoadChanges.java:49)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChangesForCheckoutRules(LoadChanges.java:24)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChangesByEachRule(LoadChanges.java:34)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChangesByCombinedRule(LoadChanges.java:42)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChanges(LoadChanges.java:47)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.VcsRootChangesLoader$RunLoadChanges.run(VcsRootChangesLoader.java:66)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.util.NamedThreadFactory.executeWithNewThreadName(NamedThreadFactory.java:89)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.VcsRootChangesLoader.loadChanges(VcsRootChangesLoader.java:94)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesFetcher$LoadChangesForRoot.run(VcsChangesFetcher.java:21)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesLoaderImpl$ImmediateFutureExecService$1.call(VcsChangesLoaderImpl.java:2)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.ImmediateFuture.get(ImmediateFuture.java:59)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.ImmediateFuture.get(ImmediateFuture.java:68)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.PeriodicChangesLoader.waitForTaskToComplete(PeriodicChangesLoader.java:20)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.PeriodicChangesLoader.loadChanges(PeriodicChangesLoader.java:26)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesLoaderImpl.tryLoadChanges(VcsChangesLoaderImpl.java:28)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.VcsModificationChecker$CollectChangesAction$1.run(VcsModificationChecker.java:14)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.util.NamedThreadFactory.executeWithNewThreadName(NamedThreadFactory.java:89)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.VcsModificationChecker$CollectChangesAction.run(VcsModificationChecker.java:6)
>
> at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>
> at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>
> at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull
>   parameter 'message' of
>   jetbrains/buildServer/buildTriggers/vcs/vault/impl/VaultConnectionImpl.specifyMessage
>   must not be null
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.impl.VaultConnectionImpl.specifyMessage(VaultConnectionImpl.java)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.impl.VaultConnectionImpl.login(VaultConnectionImpl.java:260)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.impl.VaultConnectionImpl.login(VaultConnectionImpl.java:238)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.DelegatingVaultConnection.login(DelegatingVaultConnection.java:49)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.ExceptionAwareConnection.login(ExceptionAwareConnection.java:115)
>
> ... 34 more
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter
>   'message' of
>   jetbrains/buildServer/buildTriggers/vcs/vault/impl/VaultConnectionImpl.specifyMessage
>   must not be null
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.impl.VaultConnectionImpl.specifyMessage(VaultConnectionImpl.java)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.impl.VaultConnectionImpl.login(VaultConnectionImpl.java:260)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.impl.VaultConnectionImpl.login(VaultConnectionImpl.java:238)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.DelegatingVaultConnection.login(DelegatingVaultConnection.java:49)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.ExceptionAwareConnection.login(ExceptionAwareConnection.java:115)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.EternalVaultConnection.ensureActiveConnection(EternalVaultConnection.java:44)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.EternalVaultConnection.refresh(EternalVaultConnection.java:67)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.connection.SynchronizedVaultConnection.refresh(SynchronizedVaultConnection.java:77)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.vault.VaultVcsSupport$3.collectChanges(VaultVcsSupport.java:261)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.utils.VcsPluginUtil.collectBuildChanges(VcsPluginUtil.java:99)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.vcs.api.services.collectChanges.CollectRepositoryChangesPolicyFactory$7.collectChanges(CollectRepositoryChangesPolicyFactory.java:3)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.vcs.api.services.collectChanges.SingleVersionCollectChangesCommand.collectChanges(SingleVersionCollectChangesCommand.java:0)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.vcs.api.services.collectChanges.CollectChangesServiceProvider$1.collectChanges(CollectChangesServiceProvider.java:4)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges$CollectChangesForCheckoutRules.call(LoadChanges.java:0)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges$CollectChangesForCheckoutRules.call(LoadChanges.java:1)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsOperationProgressProviderImpl.runWithProgress(VcsOperationProgressProviderImpl.java:27)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChangesWithProgress(LoadChanges.java:49)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChangesForCheckoutRules(LoadChanges.java:24)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChangesByEachRule(LoadChanges.java:34)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChangesByCombinedRule(LoadChanges.java:42)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChanges(LoadChanges.java:47)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.VcsRootChangesLoader$RunLoadChanges.run(VcsRootChangesLoader.java:66)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.util.NamedThreadFactory.executeWithNewThreadName(NamedThreadFactory.java:89)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.VcsRootChangesLoader.loadChanges(VcsRootChangesLoader.java:94)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesFetcher$LoadChangesForRoot.run(VcsChangesFetcher.java:21)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesLoaderImpl$ImmediateFutureExecService$1.call(VcsChangesLoaderImpl.java:2)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.ImmediateFuture.get(ImmediateFuture.java:59)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.ImmediateFuture.get(ImmediateFuture.java:68)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.PeriodicChangesLoader.waitForTaskToComplete(PeriodicChangesLoader.java:20)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.PeriodicChangesLoader.loadChanges(PeriodicChangesLoader.java:26)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesLoaderImpl.tryLoadChanges(VcsChangesLoaderImpl.java:28)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.VcsModificationChecker$CollectChangesAction$1.run(VcsModificationChecker.java:14)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.util.NamedThreadFactory.executeWithNewThreadName(NamedThreadFactory.java:89)
>
> at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.VcsModificationChecker$CollectChangesAction.run(VcsModificationChecker.java:6)
>
> at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>
> at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>
> at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this on JetBrains issue tracker, and they've classified it as a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-45147), so I suppose the answer is to wait for a patch.